# Dynamic non None checking while filtering with snowpark Session

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using `snowflake.snowpark.Session` object how to implement non `None` checking dynamically for parameters (python variables which comes from http request and can be `None`) which need to be passed into `filter` method of `snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame` object?

```
a_value = "test";  # can be null
b_value = "12"  # can be null
tbl_to_read = session.table(table_name).filter(
                                               (col("a").__eq__(a_value)) &  # check on non null to avoid passing filtering by null in database
                                               (col("b").gt(b_value))
)
```

It would be great if there is solution which allows doing this check into functional style (pipeline).